# VBA Replace a cell value from looping through a list in another sheet and save

Tags: vba, excel

There are 2 sheets.

-In Sheet1, cell "A1", I'm trying to change the value of it from a list in Sheet2

-In Sheet2, there is a list of 10 names. I want to loop through the list and replace the cell value "A1" in Sheet1.

-Once the cell "A1" is replaced with a name (taken from the list of 10 names), I want to save that excel file according to it's name and repeat the process for 10 times. Ideally, I would have 10 excel files saved as 10 different names from that list each containing a cell value in "A1" in Sheet1. (For example, if one of the name from the list is Anne, "A1" in Sheet1 will have Anne & it would have been saved as "Anne" in excel file. If I can get a VBA code to avoid doing this manually, it would be nice.

Comment: Can you re-select the correct answer and possibly edit your original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need the Developer Ribbon set up.  Next you create a Macro, here is my code:

```
Sub Macro1()
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
Range("A1").Select

Do While True
    If Selection.Value = "" Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
        Range("A1").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\jared_000\Desktop\" & Selection.Value & ".xlsm", _
            FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

        Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select

    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

It is important to have a blank cell after the list of names in Sheet2 (that's my condition to stop looping through.  You can set this macro to a hot-key or create a button using the Developer Ribbon (my preference).  If you don't want them to have a macro-enabled workbook then FileFormat would be xlWorkbookNormal.  I've included a screenshot of what the button looks like and the final results on my desktop.  Hope this helps!

[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pn07z.png)

[Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOjh4.png)

Comment: Thank you so much Jared. For the file name to be saved, I actually have a cell "C18" where a value changes automatically with cell "A1" change in Sheet1. To have the files to be named by whatever the value in C18 is, how can I modify the code?

Comment: @ScottJ - you did not mention that in your original question, you wrote, "For example, if one of the name from the list is Anne, "A1" in Sheet1 will have Anne & it would have been saved as "Anne" in excel file"

Comment: I apologize for not mentioning in my question. I think I tried to simplify too much.

Answer (score 0):

To copy a sheet into a new workbook, you just need, `Sheets("Sheet1").copy`

So loop through the list in sheet2 and place the list into sheet1 range("A1"), then copy and save the sheet.

This will save the sheet as a, .xlsx workbook

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, LstRw As Long, c As Range
    Dim a As Range
    Dim dir As String

    dir = "C:\Users\Dave\Downloads\MyFolder\"    'change folder location, make sure you have the "\" at the end
    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set a = sh.Range("A1")
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

    With ws

        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & LstRw)

        For Each c In rng.Cells

            a = c
            sh.Copy
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=dir & sh.Range("C18").Value & ".xlsx", _
                                  FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Next c

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Code edited so the workbook is saved as Sheet1.Range("C18")